# Creating a new formula of type `~ x + y` using `rlang`

Tags: r, rlang, quosure

I am trying to write a custom function where I want to use the `cor.test` function but I am having trouble unquoting the needed arguments to create a working formula.

Here is what I currently have that doesn't work-

```r
library(rlang)

# custom function
tryfn <- function(data, x, y) {
  stats::cor.test(
    formula = rlang::new_formula(NULL, {{ x }} + {{ y }}),
    data = data,
    method = "pearson"
  )
}

# using the function
tryfn(mtcars, wt, mpg)
#> Error in rlang::new_formula(NULL, {: object 'wt' not found
```

I tried this way because it seems to work if I don't have to unquote the formula in the function environment.

```r
# without unquoting inside another function
print(rlang::new_formula(NULL, quote(x + y)))
#> ~x + y
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Can you try with `tryfn(mtcars, quote(mpg + wt))` and inside the `formula = rlang::new_formula(NULL, expr)` and `function(data, expr)`

Comment: That works, but I must have a function with arguments `data`, `x`, and `y`, so this still won't solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to remember that `rlang::quo` is not the same as `base::quote`.
In practice, the latter ends up being essentially equivalent to `rlang::expr`.
Interpolation with `{{` creates quosures with their corresponding environments,
so it's a shortcut for a case like the following:

```
x <- 0

with_curly <- function(foo) {
  x <- 1
  rlang::eval_tidy({{ foo }})
}

with_curly(x)
# 0

with_enquo <- function(foo) {
  x <- 1
  rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::enquo(foo))
}

with_enquo(x)
# 0
```

On the other hand, `enexpr` acts like `quote` but for what the user typed:

```
with_enexpr <- function(foo) {
  x <- 1
  rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::enexpr(foo))
}

with_enexpr(x)
# 1
```

In my experience, quosures don't play nicely (or at all) with any function that doesn't support them explicitly,
and many R functions expect "raw" expressions.
Even during printing you can see that they aren't treated the same:

```
foo <- function(foo) {
  rlang::qq_show({{ foo }})
  rlang::qq_show(!!rlang::enexpr(foo))
  invisible()
}

foo(x)
# ^x
# x
```

That means, at least for now, there's no shortcut for creation of simple expressions,
and you'll have to do it the long way:

**EDIT**: not entirely true.
There's no shortcut for simple expressions,
but you can still create formulas with quosures.
See Moody's answer and the comments below.

---

It's also worth taking a step back every now and then and remember that you don't need non-standard evaluation everywhere:

```
tryfn <- function(data, x, y) {
  stats::cor.test(
    formula = as.formula(glue::glue("~ {x} + {y}")),
    data = data,
    method = "pearson"
  )
}

tryfn(mtcars, "wt", "mpg")
```

Comment: I disagree with this, the difference between quosures and quoted expressions is irrelevant here, as OP didn't try to feed a quosure where a quoted expression was expected. `rlang::new_formula(NULL, {{ x }} + {{ y }})` would work fine if `new_formula()` supported quasi quotation and used NSE instead of expecting calls or names. See my take on this in my own answer.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Well, sort of. Notation with `{{` does create quosures. If you print the formula created in your solution, you'll see extra `~` symbols added due to the arguments being quosures, but that doesn't seem to affect the semantics of the formula, so OP could indeed use it anyway.

Comment: Indeed you're right, I'll edit my answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues come from the fact that :

- `new_formula()` requires call or name objects as inputs, and you're expecting it to use NSE :

```r
rlang::new_formula(NULL, wt + mpg)
#> Error in rlang::new_formula(NULL, wt + mpg): objet 'wt' introuvable
rlang::new_formula(NULL, quote(wt + mpg))
#> ~wt + mpg
```

- `new_formula()` doesn't support quasi-quotation :

```r
quoted_expr <- quote(wt + mpg)
rlang::new_formula(NULL, !!quote(quoted_expr))
#> Error in !quote(quoted_expr): type de l'argument incorrect
```

(see how `!!` is not recognized)

A way around both of these issues is to create a quoted expression from a function that supports quasiquotation. This function is `expr()` :

```r
tryfn <- function(data, x, y) {
  stats::cor.test(
    formula = rlang::new_formula(NULL, rlang::expr({{x}} + {{y}})),
    data = data,
    method = "pearson"
  )
}

tryfn(mtcars, wt, mpg)
#> 
#>  Pearson's product-moment correlation
#> 
#> data:  wt and mpg
#> t = -9.559, df = 30, p-value = 1.294e-10
#> alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.9338264 -0.7440872
#> sample estimates:
#>        cor 
#> -0.8676594
```

Comment: see comments below Alexis's answer too

Comment: I think a note should be made about the use of `{{}}` and how it only appears after a specific version of `rlang`. Curious why the `!!` fails but `{{}}` works. What are the fundamental differences? Also curious what the advantage would be of using `rlang` over `reformulate` and the like.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper How will the call to `rlang::new_formula` will change if the formula was not `~x + y`, but rather `y ~ x`? I tried `rlang::new_formula(rlang::expr({{x}}), rlang::expr({{y}}))`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't fuly understand what's going on but I'd go with base R, my answer could use `formula = rlang::new_formula(NULL, substitute(x + y))` or even `formula = eval(substitute(~x + y))`, so for your variant you could use `formula = rlang::new_formula(substitute(x), substitute(y))`  or `formula = eval(substitute(x ~ y))`